# Multiple index.html pages angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm brand new to angular, and am still deciding whether or not I want to use it.  I'm looking to have 2 separate 'base' pages in my app: an authenticated one and an unauthenticated one.  They have different skeletons with different content areas.  So, I can't just redirect to separate partials, but rather an overall html.

- Is there a way to have 2 apps, 1 for index1.html and one for index2.html?

OR

- Is there an easier way to do this? Or is this just not what angular is built for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ngInclude`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) to conditionally change the contents of various parts of the page.  That way your header and footer can change depending on whether or not the user is authenticated, while the main content area is still serving content based on your routes.

Comment: Secondary question: I want the basis of the unauthenticated pages be SEO.  Thus using angular for it might be out of the question (we don't want to do something as complicated as the [this](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html) ). We're thinking about using a templateing framework for unauth pages.  Is there a way to separate the two?

Comment: @jbenowitz I am not sure.  Open another question up and someone else may have an answer.

Comment: @jbenowitz If you're using Apache(for example) you can set-up some specific rules based on which you can switch between several main templates.