# How to use multiple index pages in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I want to access the localhost:3000/admin which is in my views ..
the index.html and the admin.html are my two different base files one is for users and the other is for admin dashboard respectively

in my app.routes.js I have this

```
 angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/home.html',
        controller: 'MainController',
        controllerAs: 'main'
    })
    .when('/admin', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/admin.html',
    })
    .when('/logout', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/home.html'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/login.html'
    })
    .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/signup.html'
    })
    .when('/admin/login' ,{
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/adminlogin.html'
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   })
```

in server.js I have this

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html');
});
```

there are two html index files: index.html, admin.html
i want to open admin.html when the url is: localhost:3000/admin

and index.html when the url is: localhost:3000

[screenshot of the app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4AHy.jpg)

in views/pages I have all the html pages required by index.html and admin.html using ng-view

Comment: Please state what you're asking about, as currently it's not clear what is the problem.

Comment: Possible hint for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927784/angularjs-ui-router-multiple-pages

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906231/multiple-index-html-pages-angular

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov i want to access localhost:3000/admin.. localhost:3000 is just working fine , it is rendering index.html file

Comment: Consider reading [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/239056/angularjs-structuring-a-web-application-with-multiple-ng-apps); 1st answer contains the answer to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand your question, you would want to just add one more routing rule to express. Express uses the first route that matches, so order is important here.

```
app.get('/admin/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/app/views/admin.html');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html');
});
```

The angular docs state about html5mode that you should rewrite all your urls to a single app entry point: `Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html).`
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side

So to be clear: What I suggest is that you create server-routes for **two separate** apps. Nothing prevents you from using the first app one more time on another route, but I would advice against it. Separate anything with real power over your backend from the public app. I.e. remove `/admin/login` and `/admin` from your ng-routes and simply create a separate app for that.

Comment: thanks.. now it is rendering admin.html by localhost:3000/admin
and now what you are suggesting me is that i have to create 2 ng-app i.e one for index.html and the other for admin.html ??

Comment: That's how I would do it. Dependency injection in angular makes it so easy to reuse stuff, so it's basically just another `angular.module(...`

Comment: can you provide me with a working example? I'm still having some issues. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution for this..

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
if (req.url.match('^\/admin')) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/app/views/admin.html');
} else {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html');
}
});
```