# Angular Route for sub folder gives error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have written 2 `ng-app` in one project, one is `user` and the other `admin`.
To remove the `#` from the url I had used the below code in both app.config function

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and in app/index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

and in app/admin/index.html

```
<base href="/admin/">
```

---

user app.js

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/properties', {
            templateUrl: 'views/modules/properties.html'
        })
        .when('/pages', {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/pages.html'
        })
        .when('pages/editpages', {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/editPages.html',
            controller: 'editPagesController',
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

server.js

```
app.use('/', express.static('app', { redirect: false }));

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});
```

I'm getting the following error, if there's an extra param in the route

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

[image]

The above error I get when my urls are

```
http://localhost:8080/properties/
http://localhost:8080/properties/something
http://localhost:8080/pages/
http://localhost:8080/pages/editpages
```

This works fine if the url is used without the last `/` i.e.

```
http://localhost:8080/properties
http://localhost:8080/pages
```

I have refered to this questions too but couldn't resolve the issue

[Node / Angular app Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495743/node-angular-app-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

[How to use multiple index pages in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667954/how-to-use-multiple-index-pages-in-angular)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution found**

The placement of the `<base href="/">` was just before the `</head>` before which there were all scripts and links tags. After adding the `<base href="/">` after title tag the issue was resolved

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the express middleware, take for example

```
app.use(express.static('./build/'));
// Any invalid calls for templateUrls are under app/* and should return 404
app.use('/app/*', function(req, res, next) {
  four0four.send404(req, res);
});
// Any deep link calls should return index.html
app.use('/*', express.static('./build/index.html'));
```